# how to resize ext4 partition that is mounted as /home

Tags: partitioning, windows, filesystem, ext4

On Ubuntu 21, I have a separate ext4 partition which is currently mounted as /home.  How can I shrink this partition (in order to make space for a new ntfs partition that I can use on Windows?)

Comment: Please clarify your release; Ubuntu doesn't have a 21 release; so do you mean 21.04? 21.10? or have a *snap* only release for example Ubuntu Core 20 (that uses the *year* format but are released on *even* years only)?

Comment: @guiverc I'm meant 21.04